# Why aren't pod names registered in Kubernetes DNS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

When I create a deployment in Kubernetes (specifically Amazon EKS), it spins up *N* pods:

```
worker-node-dddf68987-67fsq      192.168.149.142
worker-node-dddf68987-f77ks      192.168.155.15
worker-node-dddf68987-zndn4      192.168.232.226
```

And those pods can be resolved in DNS as (e.g.) `192-168-232-226.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local`.

But they're not resolvable as (e.g.) `worker-node-dddf68987-zndn4.my-namespace.pod.cluster.local`. **Why not?**

Every answer I've seen says something like "well actually, you really want to look up the *service*". I *don't*.

My motivation is this: when connecting Erlang nodes into a cluster, the node name must match *exactly* on both ends, and I'd prefer my node name to be `worker-node@worker-node-dddf68987-zndn4`, rather than `worker-node@192.168.232.226`.

I can set the "server" node name by using `hostname -f`, but if that name's not discoverable in DNS, the "client" node can't connect to it.

I'm aware that by using a StatefulSet, I can permanently associate a name with a pod. That's not what I want. My nodes don't have any state. I don't mind that the name changes -- I'm using libcluster, which will automatically deal with Erlang cluster membership. I just want the names to be readable.

---

Aside: the dashed IP lookup is basically a hack:

```
# ping 1-1-1-1.default.pod.cluster.local
PING 1-1-1-1.default.pod.cluster.local (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from one.one.one.one (1.1.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=1.97 ms
```

Comment: Hello, I found this link when looking for an answer for your case, I'm not an Erlang specialist but I have some experience with kubernetes and the explanation on that link is very much reasonable...take a look and let me know if you think I can help you further: [Creating an Erlang Elixir Cluster on Kubernetes](https://tech.xing.com/creating-an-erlang-elixir-cluster-on-kubernetes-d53ef89758f6)

Comment: There is an old, but still active, issue on GitHub: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60789.

Answer (score 1):

Because `kubernetes service` creates an abstraction layer in front of pods in deployments and works as a load balancer for them. Pod names are volatile and will change once you recreate the deployment or modify it.

What you're trying to achieve can be done by creating a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) to [disable load balancing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields):

> If there exists a headless service in the same namespace as the pod
>   and with the same name as the subdomain, the cluster’s DNS Server also
>   returns an A or AAAA record for the Pod’s fully qualified hostname.

Or just use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for which a headless service is required

> Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod.

Comment: "Pod names are volatile and will change once you recreate the deployment or modify it." -- Yep. I'm cool with that. Erlang will move them in and out of the cluster when that happens.

"designed exactly to have a stable network identifiers" -- I don't want stable network identifiers; I want human-readable names.

Comment: human readble and non-volatile pod names are also a part of  StatefulSets concept. Just get familiar with concepts of Deployments and StatefulSets.It seems like you're trying to use kubernetes abstractions in the way they weren't designed for.

Comment: But I'm not asking for them to be non-volatile. My question is *why* does K8s conflate human readable with non-volatile? Why *are* they designed that way? What does it hurt to also register the pod name in DNS?

Comment: In this case you need to switch off load balancing by creating a "headless service"
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/
"If there exists a headless service in the same namespace as the pod and with the same name as the subdomain, the cluster’s DNS Server also returns an A or AAAA record for the Pod’s fully qualified hostname."
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services